# Image Stitching Emgu CV with GPU

Tags: c#, runtime-error, emgucv, image-stitching

I am running a EmguCV example for Image Stitching. Here's the important code from that example:

```
    try
    {
        using (Stitcher stitcher = new Stitcher(false))
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> result = stitcher.Stitch(sourceImages);
            IMGBXDisplayStitched.Image = result;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (Image<Bgr, Byte> img in sourceImages)
        {
            img.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

It works well, but when I change the value of `Stitcher()` to true (I want to use GPU), it shows this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
>   Additional information: OpenCV: You should explicitly call download method for gpu::GpuMat object

How can I solve this?

Comment: At what line is the exception happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [this example page](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Image_Stitching_in_CSharp), it says

> There is currently a bug in Open CV such that GPU processing cannot produce the correct result. Must specify false as parameter. Hope this will be fixed soon to enable GPU processing